# How do I exclude a common name from a search result in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've been refreshing our companies laptops and I had an interesting question brought up to me. A user asked "Will all of my Wi-Fi networks that I've connected to come over to my new machine?"

Now in the past, all I've done was put our Corporate WiFi networks on the new machine and let the user go and seek out the other wireless network keys themselves.

But since this question was brought up to me, I looked around and found a PowerShell script that pulls all WiFi connection profiles and their passwords, and it dumps them on a file to their desktop. We would then copy that log file and put it on their new machine's desktop.

Pretty handy if the user has to connect to a network with complex characters.

My issue is, I'm not the only member on the team doing these laptop refreshes and there have been times where we forget to go into the log file and delete the Corporate WiFi network since we don't want users to have that Password.

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  | Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\DESKTOP\Wifi.log
```

I tried to add a where clause after select-string |but it doesn't work

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | Where {$name -notcontains "OUR CORP SSID"}| %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  | Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\DESKTOP\Wifi.log
```

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  | Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\DESKTOP\Wifi.log
```

Expected result: Show all SSIDs EXCEPT for the Corporate SSIDs

Actual result: It still shows in the list.

Comment: the thing that may be glitching for you is that `Select-String` **_does not return strings_** - it returns `MatchInfo` objects. they get shown on the display as strings ... but the usual string stuff will fail since they _are not strings_. [*grin*] --- try using `.ToString()` to make it into strings to work on. ///// also, are you sure that the `netsh` call is returning _strings_ or one multi-line string? if the 2nd of those, then `Select-String` will always return the whole multiline string.

Comment: @Lee_Daily, his code does not assume that it returns a string.  He always reads the `$_.Matches` object in his next `ForEach-Object`

Comment: @twinlakes - ah! i managed to miss that. [*blush*] thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do, but I believe at the root you are trying to ensure that your sensitive file is deleted no matter what.  In that case you should apply the `try`/`finally` pattern.  I would also recommend not putting the file somewhere where the user would see it--instead put it in their temp folder.

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$path = "$env:TEMP\..." # path to the temporary sensitive file
try {
    # in here, create the sensitive file
} finally {
    Remove-Item $path -Force
}
```

Comment: The file it produces is a list of all wifi connections the user has ever connected to. I want to provide that info for them, but I wanted to exclude our corp wifi from the list.

Comment: Can you start by writing two separate functions: `function Test-SsidIsCorp([string]$Ssid) {...}` that returns `$true` if `$Ssid` is a corporate SSID, and a `function Get-Ssid() {...}` that returns all SSIDs on your system?  Once you have those, we can build up a better pipeline leveraging those functions.